# Unable to locate an element using xpath error in selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
public WebDriver createPart() {

    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("502409373");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Magic14Magic");
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitFrmShared")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Select dropCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("txtNewLocation")));
        dropCountry.selectByVisibleText("India");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn']/label")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='icon-button add']/span")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ENCActions']/a/label")).click();    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(text(),'Create Part...')]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
        String subWindowHandler = null; 
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Type-Field']//following-sibling::div//div//input"));
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        element.sendKeys("Subassy");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-value='Subassy']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Description']//parent::td//following-sibling::td//textarea")).sendKeys("Testing");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='BioSc-DS-Chemical']//parent::select")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='BioSc-DS-Chemical']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Done']")).click();
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));
        element.click();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return driver;

}
```

This is the html code of the element, I am unable to find.

```
<div class="tabcontent">
<a class="tablink" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Part Details" 
onclick="tvcTabPage_tabClicked(this,true)">Part Details</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closetab" 
onclick="tvcTabPage_tabClosed(this)" title="Close Tab"></a>
</div>
```

This is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected 
condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: 
//a[@title='Part Details'] (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS 
interval)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an 
element using By.xpath: //a[@title='Part Details']
```

Even though I have used wait statement. I am unable to locate the element. I have verified the xpath using chrome xpath. Please help me resolving my issue.
Selenium version:3.3.1. The actual flow is, I am clicking a link in main page which results a popup consisting a form. After filling the form and clicking on done, popup gets closed automatically and main page gets refreshed and a new page is opened. Now, I am trying to click on the Part Details link in the new main page which is not working.

I have added this peice of code to find the right window handler.

```
subWindowHandler = null;
        Set<String> handles1 = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        iterator = handles1.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
            element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));
            System.out.println("KK1");
        }
```

Giving me the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected 
condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: 
//a[@title='Part Details'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS 
interval)
```

Here, required 'Part Details' element is located in a frame which I have included in code. But, i am unable to locate the element inside the frame.
This is my modified code.

```
System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler).getTitle());           
        driver.switchTo().frame("content");         
        driver.switchTo().frame("detailsDisplay");          
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")).click();
```

But I am facing this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no 
such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Part Details']"}
```

I have attached my screenshot of the html code.
[HTML screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtPRQ.png)

Comment: Try using class driver.find_element_by_class_name("tablink")

Comment: Also try: //*[@title="Part Details"]

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov , and what is the point? Target element is, obviously, a link - there is no need in using wild-card for tag name

Comment: So in the original question you wanted us to help you in solving `element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));` after `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);` Now, as per your question update you wanted us to help you in solving `element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));` after `driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);`

Comment: Those 2 are suggestions posted here. Either way it is not working. I think I am unable to find the right window handler after the page gets refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Change `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of `elementToBeClickable`.
You can directly find the webeelement, and then click on it as shown below:

```
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `click()` on the link with text as **Part Details** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and invoke `click()` as follows :

- *linkText* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Part Details"))).click();
  ```
- *cssSelector* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.tablink[title='Part Details']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='tablink' and @title='Part Details']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: @kirankumar `Still the same error` doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code trials and error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

your `parentWindowHandler` should not be correct, you fetch it at wrong time point.

Try move below code line to the first line in the `try` block

```
try {
   String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
```

Comment: Seem the link `//a[@title='Part Details']` not inside the first window, please manual check and find out this link inside which window, then jump into that window.

Comment: Ok. How to do that?

Comment: Assume, before this code line: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));` be executed,   Selenium had opened 1 browser window with 2 Tab (Selenium will treat each Tab as another window even those tabs in same browser window).  And assume Tab1 includes 1 frame/iframe,  Tab2 includes 1 frame/iframe (frame/iframe will also be treated as another window), So far now `driver.getWindowHandles()` will return 4 window handles.  So you need to confirm your link inside which frame of which Tab. Search tag frame/iframe to see Tab has frame.

Comment: **subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles1 = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
iterator = handles1.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));
System.out.println("KK1");
}**
I have written this while to findout in which window handler element is present. According to the output, I see there are 3 window handlers.
But i am unable to locate the element with this peice of code.

Answer (score 0):

Once switched to parent window, try to refresh the page then find the element as given below. It may solve your issue.

```
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
    driver.navigate().refresh();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Part Details']")));
    element.click();
```

Comment: If I do refresh, current page goes back to home page. So I can't do that.